# How to write a query for reordering elements

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a code that will have a list of items in a specific order and I'd like to reorder them at will. The setup isn't really that important, but to summarize it, it's a node server with MSSQL database.

For the sake of the demonstration lets say we're discussing forum categories that show in a specific order.

```
Id | OrderNumber | Name
------------------------
1  | 1           | Rules
2  | 3           | Off-topic
5  | 2           | General
8  | 4           | Global
```

I've already handled the front end that will allow me to reorder them as I like and the problem is **what should happen when I press the save button on the database.**

Ideally I'd like to send a JavaScript object containing item IDs in the right order to the API endpoint on the server that will execute a stored procedure. Something like:

```
Data = {
    IDs:"5,2,8,1"
}
```

Is there a way that I can program a that stored procedure that it's only parameter is the list of Ids but that it can go through that list and do something I can only describe as the following pseudo code:

```
var Order = 1;
foreach ID in Data.IDs
   UPDATE Categories SET OrderNum = Order WHERE Id = ID
   Order = Order + 1
```

My biggest problem is that I'm not very experienced with advanced SQL commands, but that's the only part I need help with, I handled everything else already. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are going to have to explain a lot here. What defines the "right order"? What exactly are you struggling with? I would urge you to read your question and pretend you know nothing about your project and see if you would be able to answer this.

Comment: @SeanLange imagine a forum with multiple sections/categories etc. Each category shows itself in a specific order . Let's say 1. Rules, 2. General, 3. Off topic. And then imagine a front end page where you can reorder them, and when you press save this calls a database procedure to update the ordering of the categories. I'm looking for a way to do this in one query.

Comment: This is so vague I don't even know where to begin. Maybe you need to look at table valued parameters?

Comment: @SeanLange I apologize for the question being vague. I've written it again and hopefully now it's more understandable what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @IDs varchar(max) = '5,2,8,1'

Update A
   set OrderNumber=B.RetSeq
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
        Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by (select null))
              ,RetVal = B.n.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
         From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(@IDs,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) )) A(xmldata)
         Cross Apply xmldata.nodes('x') B(n)
      ) B on A.ID=B.RetVal
```

**Updated Table**

```
Id  OrderNumber Name
1   4           Rules
2   2           Off-topic
5   1           General
8   3           Global
```

Comment: Hello.. looking at your reply, I don't think that that's what I need, I do thank you for the attempt though. I've revised the question so it's easier to understand what exactly I need help with. Could you please check it again?

Comment: Thank you for the updated reply. I'll give this a try tomorrow. Could you please elaborate a bit on the join subselect? I'm unsure I fully understand anything between Select and From and from From to ) B. What does XML have to do with this and why is it important?

Comment: @DethoRhyne Alias B will generate a small table by parsing the delimited string of IDs.  The XML is used to parse the string.